# Do you set a one or two commas when using \mapsto?

Tags: mathematical-writing, soft-question

I am currently revising a paper and I am completely confused about the commas. Is it correct English to write

1) "The canonical map $X \to Y$, $x \mapsto f(x)$, is injective."

or is it

2) "The canonical map $X \to Y$, $x \mapsto f(x)$ is injective." ,

i.e. is the second comma mandatory, optional or wrong?

Comment: It would be best to write "The canonical map $X\to Y$ given by $x\mapsto f(x)$ is injective". Neither 1) nor 2) sound like full sentences to my ear, and one should always avoid "(maths),(maths)"! 

Comment: I believe 1) is grammatically correct as the part between the commas can be considered a parenthesis (in the syntactic sense of the word), but I agree that it is best avoided.

Comment: In the case in question one can just write "The canonical map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is injective".

Answer (score 6):

Halmos's advice in "How to write mathematics" is never use punctuation to separate notation.